# Why must I override toString method instead of just creating another method?

Tags: java

Is there anything special about toString that makes it unique and more useful to Override compared to just leaving the toString method alone and create a separate method.

For example the following codes. What is the advantage/ disadvantage to Override toString method? Both the methods returns the same output.

```
@Override
public String toString(){ 
    return String.format("%s is a %s", "Apple", "fruit.");
}

public String newMethod(){
    return String.format("%s is a %s", "Apple", "fruit.");
}
```

Comment: your `toString()` method is called by the `JVM` when necessary. For example, `System.out.println(<any object>);`

Comment: Sorry, but this question is tagged as `Java` only and I see it in my `C#` only questions list. A SO bug?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is either fully opinion based (possible rant) or lacks the minimal understanding of Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you implement the `toString()` method, you can do things like:

```
MyType myobject = new MyType();
System.out.println(myobject);
```

This will automatically call the `toString()` method.

If you were to implement your own method, and call it `newMethod()`, you would have to do this:

```
MyType myobject = new MyType();
System.out.println(myobject.newMethod());
```

You can read more details about the `toString()` method [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/override-tostring-method-java-tips-example-code.html) and [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=55).

Answer (score 11):

You should do it for 2 main reasons (there may be more):

1. **It's a convention**. By adhering to a convention, other users of you class will instinctively know how to use them. For example, if I wanted a string representation of a class that you built, my first thought would be to call `toString` on it. I would *never* think of calling a custom method for this.
2. **Framework classes were built with this in mind**. For example, `System.out.println(myObj)` will call `ToString` on `myObj`.

Answer (score 5):

The advantage to overriding is that Java automatically will use it instead of the `toString()` provided by `Object`.

Try running

```
System.out.println(yourObject);
```

with and without the

```
@Override
public String toString(){ 
    return String.format("%s is a %s", "Apple", "fruit.");
}
```

method and observe the difference.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever the object is to be printed in it's string form, for example when you do `System.out.print(object)`, the `toString()` is called. So it's a implementation convention, and you should stick to it.

Answer (score 2):

`toString()` is inherited by `Object`, so any object in Java can call this method.

As others said, it is used by several methods, like `System.out.println(someObject)`.

If for some reason you really want another method doing the same that `toString()` does but with another name, you can do this:

```
@Override
public String toString(){ 
    return String.format("%s is a %s", "Apple", "fruit.");
}

public String newMethod(){
    return toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Within Java toString() is the standard method for converting any object to its corresponding String representation. Because this is standardized, all sorts of code can rely upon it, including debugging code that may recursively print out an object graph using Reflection.

If you want your method to be able to participate in this, then you override toString(). If, on the other hand, you are creating a method that returns some arbitrary String and you don't want it to become the object's canonical toString() representation (which presumably the existing toString() method does better), then you give it an alternative name like newMethod().

The default toString() method inherited from Object is not that useful. It just returns the object's class and hash code.

Answer (score 1):

The `toString` method is called when the instance needs to be converted to a string, for example, when you are doing something like a `System.out.println(something)` (in java) or `Console.WriteLine(something)` (in C#). It's also usefull because you can see the `toString` output when you are displaying variable values using **debuggers**.

Answer (score 1):

Just because JVM will call an Object's toString() by default and you do not have to call it explicitly.

If you go ahead with the `newMethod()` implementation, you will have to print it like : `sysout(objOfYourClass.newMethod());`
If you override toString(), you can simply right : `sysout(objOfYourClass);`

Answer (score 1):

The `ToString()` method is a method which each and every object has. Therefore when you dont know what your object is, you can always call `ToString()` on it. Also, a lot of methods use the `ToString()` method, such as `Console.WriteLine`(C#) and `System.out.println`(Java)

Answer (score 1):

One liner: System.out.println(yourclassobject) will implicitly call toString().

Answer (score 0):

Since JVM doesn't call your custom method other than the `toString()` the case you call `System.out.println(obj);` you have to override `toString()`

Answer (score 0):

Every object is expected to have a `toString` method, so you can always invoke it and expect to receive a string representation of that object.

For example `System.out.println` relies on it to print an object's string representation to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

The toString method is intended, as the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) specifies, to provide *a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a **person** [my emphasis] to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.* It is useful for debugging and logging, but the result could be changed without intentionally breaking the contract. For a precise string representing the object it is best to provide a separate method, such as *name* in the case of enums. Such a method should not change.

The default toString is generally not so useful, therefor the recommendation to override it.